# How many natural numbers are multiples of both a and b?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

The discussion at [How many integers are neither multiples of 2 nor...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673365/how-many-integers-from-1-through-100-are-neither-multiples-of-2-nor-multiples-of) suggests that all common multiples of a and b are multiples of $lcm(a,b)$ and this seems to be true. Certainly all multiples of $lcm(a,b)$ are multiples of a and b, but how do I show that there are no others?

Comment: I don't understand... You are asking why every common multiple of $a$ and $b$ is necessarily a multiple of the least common multiple of $a,b$?

Comment: @JMoravitz, that seems to be accurate. The question in the title is certainly both misleading and nonsensical.

Comment: @JMoravitz It's like asking whether every common factor of $a$ and $b$ is a factor of $\gcd(a,b)$; true but not entirely trivial.

Comment: If you meant to ask something different then please clarify and we can reopen it then.

Comment: @Carlo, understand the question as "how many natural numbers less than N are multiples of both a and b". It is obvious that you have to limit the numbers to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m=ac$ be a multiple of $a$. Then $m$ is also a multiple of $b$ iff
$$ac\equiv0\pmod b.$$
Solving for $c$, this is equivalent to
$$c\equiv0\pmod{\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}}.$$
So the admissible $c$ are precisely the multiples of $b/\gcd(a,b)$, and so the
common multiples $m$ of $a$ and $b$ are precisely the multiples of $ab/\gcd(a,b)$,
that is the multiples of one fixed value, the *least common multiple* of $a$ and $b$.